# SSRS Parameter and Filter issue

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS 2014 report. I have few issues with the Vehicle List parameter:

1. The Vehicle list parameter is not editable. [image: See this image] I set the data type to integer when I created the parameter. Can someone help me with making this filed editable? Also, it should be able to accept text as well.
2. I want to filter the Vehicle List parameter with the below expression:

   ```
   =Mid(Fields!VH_ID.Value,InStr(Fields!VH_ID.Value,"-")+ 1,2)
   ```

Can someone help me with filtering the parameter with the above expression?

Comment: You have to select the dates before that textbox will become editable. Or you can move it before the dates.

Comment: Thank you StevenWhite. I figured that out later when I posted this. But how can I filter using the above expression?

Comment: Show the query for the Vehicle List. You should be able to put it in there.

Comment: This is my query for Vehicle List                                                                          =Mid(Fields!VH_ID.Value,InStr(Fields!VH_ID.Value,"-")+ 1,2)                              I have put this in the Report Parameter Properties->Available Values->Get values from query. Is that you were asking about?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to filter your dataset by comparing the selected parameter value to a part of the vehicle ID column.

You can do this by adding a Filter expression to the dataset as shown here:

[image]

**EDIT** To handle multiple values

- Set the parameter to allow multiple values.
- Ideally, you would have a query that populates the Available Values for the parameter
- Change the dataset filter to use an `In` operator like this:

[image]

Note that the top Expression refers to the column in your dataset and the Value is your parameter. The Value expression should look like `=Parameters!MyParam.Value` with no "(0)" at the end of it.

Comment: Steve thank you for your reply. Can I filter my whole report using your above suggestion? I want to filter my report with the Vehicle Parameter.I tried implementing your suggestion but there is no data in the report(The report is coming blank) Any suggestions please?

Comment: Also how can I achieve this if I want to have the following vehicle number :          Single Vehicle: 1  or                                                                                         List: 1,3,5                 or                                                                      Range: 3-6              or                                                                              List of Range: 1,3-6,8       and For all vehicles: All.                                                                                       How can I have comma delimited and dashes in my parameter?